Jmeter JSON Extractor path for Array with backslash "\" in response
I'm trying to extract token from Sample response:
Response:-
{"data":{"generateCustomerToken":{"token":"{\"token":{\"accessToken\":\"eyJJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJmaXJibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJjZG15dWxkeHVjIiwib3JnX2xvZ28iOJlRGlzcGxheU5hbWUiOiJMRyBFbGVjdHJvbmljcyIsIm9yZ19uYW1lIjoiR2VuZXJhbCIsInB1cmNoYXNlXOTQzLCJleHAiOjE3MTMyMjIxNDN9.e-IZ7adbDchuejyTgpslCWgJXoPBUXq6eaa6K_qJePpgqaWgIFsulevK5ksobaoWP58wOOlIJKdECXC80GlM5y0SS2RIoxlKJF3-ROKr7BLKPMIZvYdhXQmRr4\",\"refreshToken\":\"eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjE4OTMsInzEzMjE0OTQzLCJleHAiOjE3MTMyMTg1NDN9.rpSCnvNOnh09LqYVqs9QV-bUPjedJiV_3IrHaUvAMC0\"}}"}}}
Below is my JSON Extractor path:  $.data.generateCustomerToken.token
As there are \ in the response from 2nd token array, normal extractor path is NOT working.
I was only able to extract until:
jwtToken={"token":{"accessToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QJ9.eyJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiJ6dXBpZ3p3dmljIiwibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJjZG15dWxkeHVjIiwib3JnX2xvZ28iOiIiLCJzdG9yZV9uYHJvbmljcyIsIm9yZ19uYW1llX2xpbWl0IjoiIiwiaWF0IjoxNzEzMjE0OTQzLCJleHAiOjE3MTMyMjIxNDN9.e-IZ7adbDchuejyTgpslCWgJXoPBUXq6eaa6K_qJePpgqaWgIFsulevK5y0SS2RIoxlKJF3-ROKr7pX4qLvVCnCYdhXQmRr4","refreshToken":"eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjETQzLCJleHAiOjE3MTMyMTg1NDN9.rpSCnvNOnh09LqYVqs9QV-
How to handle this \ in response to extract accessToken, I'm open to use Regular Expression Extractor if any one can share the expression

Now go ahead and add another JSON Extractor which will extract accessToken attribute value from ${jwtToken} JMeter Variable

First JSON Extractor:


Second JSON Extractor:



More information: How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing

hhmm...interesting logic :-), Appreciate your solution, I managed it with boundary extractor. but will try the above one.
